# Find Employees with consistent salary

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write to query to fetch all employees whose salaries have never changed.

For example, consider this employee table

```
Id | Salary | Month
------------------------
1  | 3000   | Jan
1  | 3000   | Feb
1  | 3000   | Mar
2  | 2000   | Jan
2  | 2500   | Feb
2  | 2500   | Mar
```

the query should only return employee Id 1. Please help.

Update: 
I tried using self join on Id and comparing salary in where clause, which did not work

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING, MAX(), MIN().

Comment: Help us help you. Show us your attempt, explain why it didn't work. Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service, please don't treat it like one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having min(salary) = max(salary);
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, This is exactly what I was looking for.